# How to strip the first two numbers and a period in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a complete newbie in python. I've been trying to strip the first two characters and a period from a file that contains this data:

```
12.This a line

13. This is a line too
14. 12 and 13 please stop fighting
```

I want to strip the `12.1` from line 1. Also, I want to remove the newline. But in line 3. there is a space after `.` I need to remove that too.

So far this is what I've tried:
import re

```
with open('linex.txt', 'r+') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        line = line[2:]
        lines.write(line)
```

Can someone guide me to get this thing done?

Comment: Dunno, while it's not a complicated question you asked it properly and it's clearly in the scope of this site. +1 from me to your question to get it back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
line = re.sub(r"^\d{2}\.", "", line).strip()
```

`^` matches only the start of the line then `\d{2}` selects two numbers, `\.` the literal dot. `sub` replaces then everything selected by the aforementioned regular expression with an empty string (the second argument). `strip()` then removes whitespace from both ends of the result.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: When I run the code, I get this error `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` (I think r+ is a read write mode.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to get everything after the first dot, then [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove all leading and trailing whitespace:

```
line = line.partition('.')[-1].strip()
```

Demo:

```
>>> sample = '''\
... 12.This a line
... 13. This is a line too
... 14. 12 and 13 please stop fighting
... '''
>>> for line in sample.splitlines(True):
...     print repr(line.partition('.')[-1].strip())
... 
'This a line'
'This is a line too'
'12 and 13 please stop fighting'
```

Using `str.partition()` does result in an *empty string* if there is no `.` in the line. The alternative is to use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a separator and limit:

```
line = line.split('.', 1)[-1].strip()
```

which will result in the original line (but stripped) if there is no period at all.

A quick demo showing the differences:

```
>>> 'foo bar baz'.partition('bar')
('foo ', 'bar', ' baz')
>>> 'foo bar baz'.partition('bar')[-1]
' baz'
>>> 'foo baz'.partition('bar')
('foo baz', '', '')
>>> 'foo baz'.partition('bar')[-1]
''
>>> 'foo bar baz'.split('bar', 1)
['foo ', ' baz']
>>> 'foo bar baz'.split('bar', 1)[-1]
' baz'
>>> 'foo baz'.split('bar', 1)
['foo baz']
>>> 'foo baz'.split('bar', 1)[-1]
'foo baz'
```

Comment: what does `sample.splitlines(true)` do?

Comment: @DerekMancina: produce separate lines from a big string with newlines still included, just like a file object would produce.

Comment: Also the linked page says Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.


I really don't get it. I'm a doctor and I have no first hand programming knowledge. Can you explain me in a simpler way?

Comment: @DerekMancina: try it out in a terminal. :-) `'foo bar baz'.partition('bar')` gives you a tuple: `('foo ', 'bar', ' baz')`; `'foo '` is the part *before* the separator, `'bar'` is the separator, and `' baz'` is the part *after*. `'foo baz'.partition('bar')` gives you `('foo baz', '', '')` instead, because there is no `bar` in that text.

Comment: @DerekMancina: so if there is no `.` period in your line, you could end up with an empty string. You could instead use `line.split('.', 1)[-1]` to get the original line back.

Comment: So tuple is similar to an array? And will it only return three lists?

Comment: @DerekMancina: a `tuple()` is a immutable (read-only) list. It'll only return three *elements* (contents of the tuple).

Comment: @DerekMancina: anything missing or wrong? You unaccepted the answer again.

Comment: The solution works :) But I'm still trying to understand it and implement it in my code.. I will accept it once I get my solution.